# Remove onblur validation from ASP.net Control

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation

I am wanting to remove the onblur event for asp.net validation, and only have the validation called when the button is clicked. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the validation events from given element

```
<body onload="removeValidationEvents();">
```

and the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeValidationEvents() {
        document.getElementById('<%=yourTextbox.ClientID%>').onkeypress = null;
        document.getElementById('<%=yourTextbox.ClientID%>').onblur = null;
        document.getElementById('<%=yourTextbox.ClientID%>').onchange = null;
    }
    </script>
```

Note that ASP.NET uses different events depending on what control you're trying to validate (e.g. you may need to add onclick to the list above).

**Also note that this is indeed a very ugly hack (as pointed in the comments below) and you should use it at your own peril.**

Comment: no,no,no - it is real hack.. not a fix. that might have some unexpected results.

Comment: I agree totally. It is an ugly hack and it may have side results. It works though and it's up to the person who asked to decide whether he should risk doing it. But yes - it's my fault not pointing that using it is dangerous. Edited for clarity. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide ValidationGroup property to button which is to be click, textbox and validation control. Same groupy name for all.

You then have to unset the onblur event of the control by right click it, choose properties, then go in event section by click flash button on top of the property window. then find onblur event and remove the calling event from its value cell.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. I have validation group the same on all inputs including button. Do you mean my inputs as control? I cannot see the event "flash" button for textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is a built-in functionality which you can enable by set "Display" property on your validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="val" Text="Please enter text" ErrorMessage="No text" ControlToValidate="txtText" Display="None" EnableClientScript="true" />
```

Now, during submit validation only 'No text' information will be displayed in SummaryValidator if you have one.

I assume that validation is still performed however you don't see the result. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want the validation do display, but only display when the button is clicked and not on the onblur event on textboxes.

Comment: So, you have two options here: 1. get rid of javascript validation and perform only server side one, than basically you would have expected result, of course you would have additional server roundtrip here. 2. Write custom javascript behavior which preclude validation mechanism during onblur - this can be achieved by a) a bit hacky javascript module (somewhat similar to Svetlin Panayotov's idea however more unobtrusive) or by overriding a basic validators mechanism and alter it a bit to achieve your goal.